# Theorem 8.3 in Paulsen's 'Completely bounded maps and operator algebras".

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, positive-semidefinite

I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem 8.3 in Paulsen's book "Completely bounded maps and operator algebras". Here is (part of) the proof:

[image]

Why can we conclude that
$$\Phi\begin{pmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} * & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}?$$

I guess it might be sufficient to show that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \le \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b^* & c\end{pmatrix} \le \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\implies b = c = 0$$
where the middle matrix is a positive matrix. However, I can't show this and it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll call the three matrices in question $0$, $A$ and $E_{11}$. For $\xi\in \mathcal H$ the inequality
$$
0\leq \left\langle A\binom{0}{\xi},\binom{0}{\xi}\right\rangle\leq\left\langle E_{11}\binom{0}{\xi},\binom{0}{\xi}\right\rangle
$$
implies $0\leq\langle c\xi,\xi\rangle\leq0$, hence $c=0$.

Moreover,
$$
0\leq\left\langle A\binom{\xi}{\eta},\binom{\xi}{\eta}\right\rangle=\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle+2\mathrm{Re}\langle \xi,b\eta\rangle.
$$
If $b\neq 0$, then there exist $\xi,\eta\in H$ such that $\langle\xi,b\eta\rangle\neq 0$. Multiplying $\eta$ by a suitable scalar makes this inner product negative and arbitrarily small, while $\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle$ stays unchanged. Thus we can make $\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle+2\mathrm{Re}\langle \xi,b\eta\rangle$ negative, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on two basic facts about a positive elements:

- its diagonal elements are positive;
- if a diagonal element is zero, then its whole row and column are zero.

If you know that elements in a C$^*$-algebra are of the form $X^*X$, you have that if $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ b^*&c\end{bmatrix}\geq0$ then
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ b^*&c\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} x&y\\ y^*&z\end{bmatrix}^*\begin{bmatrix} x&y\\ y^*&z\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} x^*x++yy^*&x^*y+yz\\ y^*x+z^*y^*&y^*y+z^*z\end{bmatrix}.
$$
From this you get that diagonal elements are positive. And if a diagonal element is zero, say $y^*y+z^*z=0$, then $y=z=0$.